# Do I need a new ssl.create_default_context() every time?

Tags: python, ssl

This is my code using a SSL context:

```
with smtplib.SMTP(host, port) as smtpserver:
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls(context=ssl.create_default_context())
    ... etc ...
```

Is the default context object a constant that can be shared and reused in a multi-threaded program? I mean creating it just once:

```
SSL_CONTEXT = ssl.create_default_context()
```

and then:

```
with smtplib.SMTP(host, port) as smtpserver:
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls(context=SSL_CONTEXT)
```

for every message sent.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `ssl.create_default_context()` can be used again (as it's purpose) after initializing it:

```
import ssl, smtplib
>>> smtp = smtplib.SMTP("mail.python.org", port=587)
>>> context = ssl.create_default_context()
>>> smtp.starttls(context=context)
```

> (220, b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')

↳ https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#best-defaults

Comment: I'm afraid that the example shown and the linked documentation do not say anything about the reusability. A new context is created for each SMTP connection.

Comment: Does it say anything about not re-using it, and have you tried it?

Comment: I could not find anything, that's why I wrote this question. I did not try. If it works, there is still a small chance of breaking something without noticing it. I'd rather avoid such risk. Anyway I do agree with you on the expected purpose of such context and hope the resusability will be confirmed.

Comment: If you read the documentation (on the page I linked) you would have known the answer; look at the examples, there are plenty showing a context being used multiple times. It's unclear what multi-threading your app is doing, although read the multiprocessing section (as it's important with `SSL` to change the `PRNG` state of the parent process with `os.fork()`).

Comment: Just apply common sense. What the context stores? Cert CA bundle & verification policy (the latter includes the "purpose" and the protocol versions our client will accept when negotiating the tls connection). Is this connection-specific? In general, nope. (Though you can specify different contexts for different connections, making it yes in particular.) Can this be reused? Obviously, yes. NB: PRNG state is not part of the [SSLContext](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/ssl.py#L479-L777) py object; it's handled within the native `libssl.so` library.

Answer (score 1):

Each connection should have its own context. You can see in the Python source code for http.client, that HTTPSConnection creates the new context for every connection.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/client.py